# Nested bracket in breqn doesn't work

Tags: brackets, breqn

I tried to use the latest version of `breqn` package to break this equation;
The result shows that it can't break the equation at Level/depth greater than 2 even by using `\setkeys{breqn}{breakdepth={4}}`, also the breaking at level/depth 2 is align right. Have you any explanation?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{breqn}
\setkeys{breqn}{breakdepth={4}}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
R
\left\{tr\left[{P}_{k+1}^{H}\left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\right)+{Q}_{k+1}^{H}\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right)\right]\right\}
%level 1
=R
\left\{tr\left[
\left(  %level 3
{A}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}{B}_{1}^{H}+{A}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}{B}_{1}^{H}+{A}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}{B}_{1}^{H}
+{\overline{A}}_{2}^{H}\overline{{R}_{k+1}}{\overline{B}}_{2}^{H}+{B}_{3}{R}_{k+1}^{H}{A}_{3}
+{\overline{A}}_{2}^{H}\overline{{R}_{k+1}}{\overline{B}}_{2}^{H}+{A}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}
\right)
% level 2
+\left(  %level 3
{C}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}{D}_{1}^{H}
+{\overline{C}}_{2}^{H}\overline{{R}_{k+1}}{\overline{D}}_{2}^{H}{D}_{3}{R}_{k+1}^{H}{C}_{3}
+\overline{{D}_{4}}{R}_{k+1}^{T}\overline{{C}_{4}}
+\dfrac{{\left\Vert{R}_{k+1}\right\Vert }^{2}}{{\left\Vert {R}_{k}\right\Vert}^{2}}{Q}_{k}
+\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right)+\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right)
\right)
%level 2
+\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right)+\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right)
\right]\right\}
%level 2
=R
\left\{tr\left[ %level 2
{R}_{k+1}^{H}{A}_{1}\left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\right){B}_{1}
+{R}_{k+1}^{T}{\overline{A}}_{2}\left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\right){\overline{B}}_{2}
+{R}_{k+1}{B}_{3}^{H}\left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\right){A}_{3}^{H}
+\overline{{R}_{k+1}}{\overline{{B}_{4}}}^{H}\left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\right){\overline{{A}_{4}}}^{H}
+{R}_{k+1}^{H}{C}_{1}\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right){D}_{1}+{R}_{k+1}^{T}{\overline{C}}_{2}\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right){\overline{D}}_{2}
+{R}_{k+1}{D}_{3}^{H}\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right){C}_{3}^{H}+\overline{{R}_{k+1}}{\overline{{D}_{4}}}^{H}\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right){\overline{{C}_{4}}}^{H}
+\left(\dfrac{{\left\Vert{R}_{k+1}\right\Vert }^{2}}{{\left\Vert {R}_{k}\right\Vert}^{2}}{P}_{k}^{H}\left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\right)\,\,+{Q}_{k}^{H}\left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\right)\right)
\right]\right\}
\label{eq12}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 4):

Hmm looks like `breakdepth` doesn't work as advertised (but `breqn` is one complicated package and Michael is sadly no longer with us). This is one possible workaround

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{breqn}
\setkeys{breqn}{breakdepth=4}
\def\Left#1{\mathopen{\big#1}}
\def\Right#1{\mathclose{\big#1}}

\def\overbar#1{\overline{\strut#1}}
\def\tr{\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
R
\Left\{\tr\Left[{P}_{k+1}^{H}\Left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\Right)+{Q}_{k+1}^{H}\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right)\Right]\Right\}
%level 1
=R
\Left\{\tr\Left[
\Left(  %level 3
{A}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}{B}_{1}^{H}+{A}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}{B}_{1}^{H}+{A}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}{B}_{1}^{H}
+{\overbar{A}}_{2}^{H}\overbar{{R}_{k+1}}{\overbar{B}}_{2}^{H}+{B}_{3}{R}_{k+1}^{H}{A}_{3}
+{\overbar{A}}_{2}^{H}\overbar{{R}_{k+1}}{\overbar{B}}_{2}^{H}+{A}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}
\Right)
% level 2
+\Left(  %level 3
{C}_{1}^{H}{R}_{k+1}{D}_{1}^{H}
+{\overbar{C}}_{2}^{H}\overbar{{R}_{k+1}}{\overbar{D}}_{2}^{H}{D}_{3}{R}_{k+1}^{H}{C}_{333}
+\overbar{{D}_{4}}{R}_{k+1}^{T}\overbar{{C}_{4}}
+\dfrac{{\Left\Vert{R}_{k+1}\Right\Vert }^{2}}{{\Left\Vert {R}_{k}\Right\Vert}^{2}}{Q}_{k}
+\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right)+\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right)
\Right)
%level 2
+\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right)+\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right)
\Right]\Right\}
%level 2
=R
\Left\{\tr\Left[ %level 2
{R}_{k+1}^{H}{A}_{1}\Left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\Right){B}_{1}
+{R}_{k+1}^{T}{\overbar{A}}_{2}\Left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\Right){\overbar{B}}_{2}
+{R}_{k+1}{B}_{3}^{H}\Left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\Right){A}_{3}^{H}
+\overbar{{R}_{k+1}}{\overbar{{B}_{4}}}^{H}\Left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\Right){\overbar{{A}_{4}}}^{H}
+{R}_{k+1}^{H}{C}_{1}\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right){D}_{1}+{R}_{k+1}^{T}{\overbar{C}}_{2}\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right){\overbar{D}}_{2}
+{R}_{k+1}{D}_{3}^{H}`\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right){C}_{3}^{H}+\overbar{{R}_{k+1}}{\overbar{{D}_{4}}}^{H}\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right){\overbar{{C}_{4}}}^{H}
+\Left(\dfrac{{\Left\Vert{R}_{k+1}\Right\Vert }^{2}}{{\Left\Vert {R}_{k}\Right\Vert}^{2}}{P}_{k}^{H}\Left({V}^{\ast\,\!}-{V}_{k+1}\Right)\,\,+{Q}_{k}^{H}\Left({W}^{\ast\,\!}-{W}_{k+1}\Right)\Right)
\Right]\Right\}
\label{eq12}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And Morten has left the TeX world, so there is not many who know much about the code, let alone understand it. There are several open bugs in the current `breqn`, but we either do not have the time for it or does not quite understand the code.

Comment: ok thanks for your effort but it doesn't useful to me because the alignment doesn't seem to be good as the breaking lines not aligned with there opening bracket more than that using \big or \bigg ,...etc doesn't fit the content size do you  have any more idea

Comment: Sorry that's as much as I can do during working hours. Breqn is perhaps the most complicated code in commonly available latex packages, if it doesn't do what you want, then changing its internals requires a _lot_ of coffee

Comment: @David I'd argue that some of the LaTeX3 code is more elaborate (admittedly I might be biased).  I am hoping to rewrite `breqn` some time in the next couple of months (depending on PhD etc), so hopefully in 12 months I can start answering questions about `breqn` by telling people to use a hypothetical `xbreqn`.  To do that, I will have to understand the code of `breqn`, understand the code of `nath`, and combine the two.  Good times ahead.  One reason I think it should be easier for me now than for Michael and Morten is that engines have become faster, so I can afford to drop optimizations.